# Alternate ways of getting output from oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am executing a procedure and in that I am using dbms_output.put_line() or using another approach that is declaring a variable before and printing that variable using binding concept.

Problem statement:- My problem is that I want to fetch the values stored in buffer of dbms_output using some sql query. So is there any such query which I can use to fetch values from buffer. Ialso want to know any other approach that will help me fetch the out paramater values of a procedure without dmbs_output.

Comment: Where will you fetch the buffer, and what will you do with it? [Here's a demo of converting it to a query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19143017/266304), is that the sort of thing you had in mind? You can use `get_line` over JDBC, etc., too. Depends what you want to do. This is partly why `dbms_output` is mostly useful for debugging when you control the session.

Comment: If just for development, the simplest way: Create a logging table and do some debug/logging inserts as you would do to a log-file...

Comment: @evilive :If not for development, what are the other options?

Comment: If not for development it could be done the same way, but in that case it should (as everything else) have a proper concept. Plus there might be better ways...but I don't know them or your specific requirements.